# Error CS0246 - What is causing it and how can I fix it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am referencing an enum created in another file and am receiving error CS0246. Here is the relevant code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using ScissorsPaperRock;

namespace ScissorsPaperRock
{
    public class AIChoice
    {
        public UNIT aiChoice; // error CS0246:
        public void start()
        {
            System.Random rnd = new System.Random(); // Makes the random class.
            int AISelect = rnd.Next(0, 3);
            {
                if (AISelect == 0)
                    aiChoice = UNIT.ROCK; // Oddly enough, no errors here so far?!?!
```

For reference, this is where the enum UNIT is created.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using ScissorsPaperRock;

namespace ScissorsPaperRock
{
    public class EnumData
    {
        public enum UNIT // a (player) and b (AI)
        {
            ROCK,
            PAPER,
            SCISSORS
        }
```

It seems it wants me to use a using directory, but I'm not sure which? I have tried adding and removing the namespaces and adding the namespace as a using directive. I've searched on Unity and its page on the error only covers namespaces so and as such isn't helpful. The Microsoft page has more info, and makes me believe the issue is a missing using directive, but I don't know which one I am missing, or if the issue actually is a missing using directive.

I am using Unity 2019.4f1 Personal. This is important because this error does not seem to occur on 2019.2.8f1.

Comment: `UNIT` is a member of `EnumData`, so you need to use `public EnumData.UNIT aiChoice;`

Comment: This fixes the issue. Can I ask why it is necessary though, as it seems as though my older version of Unity does not require this. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, your other thread does help me out. So essentially, I should declare my enums at namespace level, not inside of a class? Hypothetically then, if I were to remove the namespace and class from the file where the enums were declared, would I then be able to reference the enums without needing to add the "EnumData." in front?

Comment: It's possible that before you moved to the newer version, it was defined at the namespace level like `namespace ScissorsPaperRock { public enum UNIT {...} public class EnumData {...` I don't see how it could work in any version of unity the way it is written in the question though.

Comment: You can keep the namespace, and move it out of  `EnumData` , and anywhere else in that namespace will be able to use it with `UNIT` instead of `EnumData.UNIT`. If you move it outside the namespace, code anywhere will be able to use it with `UNIT`

Comment: It is indeed correct that my previous version had it defined at namespace level and not inside of a class. As for your second comment, I believe it is better long term if I simply move the enum outside of the class and remove all namespaces. That way I can reference my enums quicker and easier. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have embedded your *enumeration type* in a *class*

The solve is to remove it from the *class*, or specify it explicitly

```
public EnumData.UNIT aiChoice;
```

Comment: This fixes the error. Thank you.

Can I ask why this is necessary in Unity 2019.4.4f1 and does not appear to be in Unity 2019.2.8f1?

Comment: @TheGloriousLobsterEmperor Its actually just C#, its in both. Double check your results

Comment: My code file in the previous version defined the enums in namespace level and not in a class. It was indeed my fault and not the fault of Unity at all!